# Better way to distribute iOS apps for testing

Tags: ios, release, beta-testing

I know StackOverflow is more for programming questions but I do still trust the community to help me if they can and of course, it's truly appreciated.

I'm trying to do research on the process of iOS development. By process I'm asking these 1 question specifically.

What's the best practice to release a build for testing?
Basically, if I write an app and I just want to release it for QA Testing and the QA testers might be in a remote location. TestFlight builds apparently take too long to be released, so, what would be the best practice to basically just send the beta version to multiple devices?

Comment: Crashlytics is quick and free.  The title of this question doesn't seem to reflect your question, however.

Comment: @trojanfoe thank you for the reference to Crashlytics, I'm checking it out right now.

Comment: I wouldn't bother with Crashlytics, it's overkill for what you're trying to do. TestFlight really doesn't "take too long" unless you have a very specific business need to make them instantly available. Before distributing externally you have to go through review the first time which takes less than a day. Every subsequent build will likely be out within 30 minutes after you upload it to Apple. Sometimes TF is slow and you get stuck in processing but it's rare that that takes longer than an hour or so.

Answer (score 0):

You may produce AdHoc builds for this purpose. If you are signed up for Individual Developer Program then you may add up to 100 devices to your account and make builds for them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm signed up for the Developer Program but, from what I read, testers would need to run iTunes to put it in. I was looking for something that wouldn't require a PC.

Comment: not necessary, there is a method of installing adhoc builds with "one link tap". you can read the details [here](http://heximal.ru/blog/en/apple/wireless-enterprise-adhoc-distribution/)